# Adding Spring for android dependency to gradle + Android studio project

Tags: android, spring, gradle, android-studio, spring-android

Official Spring for Android page mentions to add following dependency code.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android:1.0.1.RELEASE'
}
```

which is latest version of build as of this time.(as per website)
I have added it in apps' build.gradle but I get an error as

```
Error:Failed to find: org.springframework.android:spring-android:1.0.1.RELEASE
```

What is the right way to do it?
I could add google play services as dependency in the same way.

Comment: That package doesn't exist: see http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.springframework.android%22 . Their instructions are in error. FWIW I've seen weird errors with the Android-Gradle version of Spring; it seems like their packaging in general is wonky. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771014/spring-for-android-build-failing-when-including-spring-social-twitter/24787929#24787929 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22238893/android-studio-gradle-java-lang-illegalargumentexception/22256105#22256105

Comment: @ScottBarta thanks for those links. I work on the project, and I'll make sure we are tracking those.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the correct dependency for the Rest Template module. I've corrected this on the [Spring for Android](http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/) project page. Thank you very much for pointing out this error.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
}
```

Comment: It works now, I came till your twitter profile page to ask before, but thought that is not the right platform. World is small :D

Comment: Yes, it is a small world! It's usually more help for others to post questions here, but feel free to contact me other places too. And sorry again for the inconvenience with the incorrect information on the project page.

Answer (score 0):

You can find correct and lastest version on spring site. Under the Quick Start title.

http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/